# Prolog pipe partial input, user-input the rest

Tags: stream, prolog, pipe, gnu-prolog

I'm writing a prolog program with an input loop. A good deal of the input is pre-scripted in a response file. I execute this as `prolog < response.txt`. When the response file has finished, I would like the program to continue through keyboard user input. However, when the response file finishes, it does not read/1 from the keyboard, but continues to read in an endless loop `end_of_file` as its input.

I want the program to revert to user typed input once the pipe has reached the end of the file. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have to show the bit of code that you are using to detect that the file has gotten to the end.

Comment: It is not clear why you want this - do you want to emulate user input? `cat response.txt - 
 prolog` might be good enough. Otherwise indicate the file explicitly with a command line argument.

Comment: My program has a cli where, yes, I want to emulate user input, which I've been doing with prolog < response.txt. @VincentRamdhanie, my code shouldn't have anything to do with this; when I reach the end of the response file it should just stop and wait for a user to give user input, instead it just keeps going saying that "end_of_file" is what the user is typing in.

Comment: @false, I tried `cat response.txt - prolog` but that just displays the response.txt to the screen and prolog doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: I meant that there is a bar like | ('|') between `-` and `prolog`

Comment: `cat response.txt -  | prolog`

Comment: Ahhh, a shame I didn't even think to catch that... let me see if that works...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to interrogate and redirect your input stream.

Not sure which version of Prolog you're using, but SWI-Prolog has plenty of [methods](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.16%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29) for redirecting your input stream.

If the input is from a keyboard, `TTY` will equal `true`:

```
current_input(Stream), stream_property(Stream, tty(TTY)).
```

If the input is from a file, `Filename` will each the name of the file input is currently read from:

```
current_input(Stream), stream_property(Stream, file_name(Filename)).
```

You can set the `Stream` to use as an input with the `set_input/1` predicate:

```
{obtain a Stream handle}, set_input(Stream).
```

I hope you can build upon this, as I haven't yet figured out how you're supposed to ask for the keyboard input Stream.

You might have to determine which OS you're running on and set up different methods for each OS to set your input to the keyboard stream.